# performance gets worse after doing opmitze in elasticsearch

Tags: optimization, elasticsearch

I just did an [_optimize](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) operation on a cluster (10 data nodes, roughly 350,000,000 docs in total).

However, the performance gets even worse: the response time doubled or even tripled.

Any hint on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe es is still busy with the optimization? You could monitor your system to get more information about the bottleneck - if there is high load on io or network then I would say es might be still in this process. You could use [this](http://www.elastichq.org/) or [this](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) tool to get more information. If you have some money left you could use [marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/).

Comment: Optimizations should be executed when the cluster is not under load because there is heavy IO involved and could destabilize the cluster.

Comment: I made the performance tests after the optimization was done. It's quite weird to me.

Comment: The index is of 149G, 19 shards with 1 replica.

The es version is 1.4.1, and the java version is 1.7.0_71.

I have specific routing strategy and the query used in testing only goes to one shard: 
heap.percent    ram.percent              load
        51                    58                      0.33

(when it is under continues query, just one query at a time)

This specific shard has 22m docs, 10GB in size.